# Why are the root settings of Ubuntu-server different from those of Ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: 22.04, root

I know this issue has been discussed before and many instructions indicate that Ubuntu does not set a root password.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04-desktop on a VM and I checked the `/etc/shadow` file and saw the following:

```
root:!:19768:0:99999:7:::
```

I also installed Ubuntu 22.04 server, but its `/etc/shadow` is as follows:

```
root:*:19769:0:99999:7:::
```

You can see that the second column in Ubuntu-desktop has an exclamation point (!) instead of an asterisk (*).

From this [discussion](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2026413) I learned, it follows that ***** means password never established, **!** means locked.

So does Ubuntu desktop set the root password first and then lock it?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The Ubuntu installer copies the `/etc/shadow` file from the installer image